# Shader Syntax error - Unity WebGL

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am trying to build a Polygon Tool WebGL project. The project works fine in the Editor, but the shader gives a syntax error when building, namely:

```
Shader error in 'Unlit/polygon': 'Value' : syntax error syntax error at line 28 (on gles)

Compiling Vertex program 
Platform defines: UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA
```

with "line 28" being:

```
int PointNum =0;
```

I am rather unexperienced with OpenGL and HSLS, but I have been looking through the Unity Shader Manual and at the ShaderLab resources considering what might be going wrong - unfortunately with no success. You can find the shader code below, with the translated comments ([source link](http://blog.csdn.net/zzlyw/article/details/53992048)).

I'm thinking maybe I'm not assigning the value correctly? Please let me know if you spot something wrong! Any help or ideas to try are greatly appreciated :) Do let me know if you need any other files/info!

"**Polygon.shader**" file:

```
Shader "Unlit/polygon"
{
Properties  
{  
    //Define basic properties can be set from inside the editor variable  
    // _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}  
}  

CGINCLUDE
// Upgrade NOTE: excluded shader from DX11 because it uses wrong array syntax (type[size] name)
#pragma exclude_renderers d3d11
        //Incoming vertices function from the application data structure definitions 
        struct appdata  
        {  
            float4 vertex : POSITION;  
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;  
        };  
        //Incoming segment from a vertex function from the data structure definitions  
        struct v2f  
        {  
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;  
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;  
        };  
        //Define mapping variables  
        sampler2D _MainTex;  
        // float4 _MainTex_ST;  

        //Define variables for communicating with the script
        vector Value[6]; 
        int PointNum = 0;

        //Function that calculates the distance between two points
        float Dis(float4 v1,float4 v2)
        {
            return sqrt(pow((v1.x-v2.x),2)+pow((v1.y-v2.y),2));
        }   

        //Draw line segments
        bool DrawLineSegment(float4 p1, float4 p2, float lineWidth,v2f i)
        {
            float4 center = float4((p1.x+p2.x)/2,(p1.y+p2.y)/2,0,0);
            //Calculate distance between point and line  
            float d = abs((p2.y-p1.y)*i.vertex.x + (p1.x - p2.x)*i.vertex.y +p2.x*p1.y -p2.y*p1.x )/sqrt(pow(p2.y-p1.y,2) + pow(p1.x-p2.x,2));  
            //When less than or equal to half the line width, which belongs to the linear range, return true  
            float lineLength = sqrt(pow(p1.x-p2.x,2)+pow(p1.y-p2.y,2));
            if(d<=lineWidth/2 && Dis(i.vertex,center)<lineLength/2)  
            {  
                return true;  
            }  
            return false;
        }

        //To draw a polygon, this limits the number of vertices is not more than 6. You can change.
        bool pnpoly(int nvert, float4 vert[6], float testx, float testy)
        {

            int i, j;
            bool c=false;
            float vertx[6];
            float verty[6];

            for(int n=0;n<nvert;n++)
            {
                vertx[n] = vert[n].x;
                verty[n] = vert[n].y;
            }
            for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
            if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) && (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
               c = !c;
            }
            return c;
        }

        v2f vert (appdata v)  
        {  
            v2f o;  
            //Object vertices from model space to the camera cut space, or you can use the shorthand way:
            //o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);  
            o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,v.vertex);  
            //2D UV coordinate transformation can also use shorthand methods
            //o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);  
            //o.uv = v.uv.xy * _MainTex_ST.xy + _MainTex_ST.zw;  
            return o;  
        }             
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target  
        {  

            //Draw a polygon vertex
            for(int j=0;j<PointNum;j++)
            {
                if(Dis(i.vertex, Value[j])<3)
                {
                    return fixed4(1,0,0,0.5);
                }
            }
            //Draws the edges of the polygon
            for(int k=0;k<PointNum;k++)
            {
                if(k==PointNum-1)
                {
                    if(DrawLineSegment(Value[k],Value[0],2,i))
                    {
                        return fixed4(1,1,0,0.5);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(DrawLineSegment(Value[k],Value[k+1],2,i))
                    {
                        return fixed4(1,1,0,0.5);
                    }
                }

            }
            //Within the filled polygon
            if(pnpoly(PointNum, Value,i.vertex.x ,i.vertex.y))
            {
                return fixed4(0,1,0,0.3);
            }
            return fixed4(0,0,0,0);
            //fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv); 
            //return col;  
        }  
ENDCG

SubShader  
{  
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }  
    LOD 100  
    Pass  
    {  
        //Select Alpha blend mode  
        Blend  SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha  
        //In the CGPROGRAM block of code to write your own processes
        CGPROGRAM  
        //Defined segment function entry and vertex function respectively, Vert and Frag  
        #pragma vertex vert  
        #pragma fragment frag  
        //Contains the basic files, there are some macro definitions and basic functions  
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"               

        ENDCG  
    }  
}  
}
```

"**Compiled-Unlit-polygon.shader**" file:

```
    // Compiled shader for WebGL
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 
    // NOTE: This is *not* a valid shader file, the contents are provided just
    // for information and for debugging purposes only.
    // 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Skipping shader variants that would not be included into build of current scene.

    Shader "Unlit/polygon" {
    SubShader { 
    LOD 100
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    Pass {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    //////////////////////////////////
    //                              //
    //      Compiled programs       //
    //                              //
    //////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    No keywords set in this variant.
    -- Vertex shader for "gles":
    // Compile errors generating this shader.

    -- Fragment shader for "gles":
    Shader Disassembly:
    // All GLSL source is contained within the vertex program

    -- Vertex shader for "gles3":
    Shader Disassembly:
    #ifdef VERTEX
    #version 300 es

    uniform     vec4 hlslcc_mtx4x4glstate_matrix_mvp[4];
    in highp vec4 in_POSITION0;
    vec4 u_xlat0;
    void main()
    {
    u_xlat0 = in_POSITION0.yyyy * hlslcc_mtx4x4glstate_matrix_mvp[1];
    u_xlat0 = hlslcc_mtx4x4glstate_matrix_mvp[0] * in_POSITION0.xxxx + u_xlat0;
    u_xlat0 = hlslcc_mtx4x4glstate_matrix_mvp[2] * in_POSITION0.zzzz + u_xlat0;
    gl_Position = hlslcc_mtx4x4glstate_matrix_mvp[3] * in_POSITION0.wwww + u_xlat0;
    return;
    }

    #endif
    #ifdef FRAGMENT
    #version 300 es

    precision highp int;
    uniform     vec4 Value[6];
    uniform     int PointNum;
    layout(location = 0) out lowp vec4 SV_Target0;
    int u_xlati0;
    vec2 u_xlat1;
    ivec2 u_xlati1;
    bool u_xlatb1;
    float u_xlat2;
    vec2 u_xlat3;
    int u_xlati3;
    bool u_xlatb3;
    vec2 u_xlat4;
    float u_xlat5;
    vec2 u_xlat6;
    int u_xlati6;
    bool u_xlatb6;
    vec2 u_xlat7;
    float u_xlat9;
    int u_xlati9;
    bool u_xlatb9;
    float u_xlat10;
    int u_xlati10;
    vec4 TempArray0[6];
    vec4 TempArray1[6];
    void main()
    {
    for(int u_xlati_loop_1 = 0 ; u_xlati_loop_1<PointNum ; u_xlati_loop_1++)
    {
            u_xlat3.xy = gl_FragCoord.xy + (-Value[u_xlati_loop_1].xy);
            u_xlat3.xy = u_xlat3.xy * u_xlat3.xy;
            u_xlat3.x = u_xlat3.y + u_xlat3.x;
            u_xlat3.x = sqrt(u_xlat3.x);
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb3 = !!(u_xlat3.x<3.0);
    #else
            u_xlatb3 = u_xlat3.x<3.0;
    #endif
            if(u_xlatb3){
            SV_Target0 = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
            return;
            //ENDIF
            }
    }
    u_xlati0 = PointNum + int(0xFFFFFFFFu);
    for(int u_xlati_loop_2 = 0 ; u_xlati_loop_2<PointNum ; u_xlati_loop_2++)
    {
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb6 = !!(u_xlati0==u_xlati_loop_2);
    #else
            u_xlatb6 = u_xlati0==u_xlati_loop_2;
    #endif
            if(u_xlatb6){
            u_xlat6.xy = Value[0].xy + Value[u_xlati_loop_2].xy;
            u_xlat1.x = (-Value[u_xlati_loop_2].y) + Value[0].y;
            u_xlat4.xy = (-Value[0].xy) + Value[u_xlati_loop_2].xy;
            u_xlat10 = u_xlat4.x * gl_FragCoord.y;
            u_xlat10 = u_xlat1.x * gl_FragCoord.x + u_xlat10;
            u_xlat10 = Value[0].x * Value[u_xlati_loop_2].y + u_xlat10;
            u_xlat10 = (-Value[0].y) * Value[u_xlati_loop_2].x + u_xlat10;
            u_xlat4.xy = u_xlat4.xy * u_xlat4.xy;
            u_xlat1.x = u_xlat1.x * u_xlat1.x + u_xlat4.x;
            u_xlat1.x = sqrt(u_xlat1.x);
            u_xlat1.x = abs(u_xlat10) / u_xlat1.x;
            u_xlat4.x = u_xlat4.y + u_xlat4.x;
            u_xlat4.x = sqrt(u_xlat4.x);
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb1 = !!(1.0>=u_xlat1.x);
    #else
            u_xlatb1 = 1.0>=u_xlat1.x;
    #endif
            u_xlat6.xy = (-u_xlat6.xy) * vec2(0.5, 0.5) + gl_FragCoord.xy;
            u_xlat6.xy = u_xlat6.xy * u_xlat6.xy;
            u_xlat6.x = u_xlat6.y + u_xlat6.x;
            u_xlat6.x = sqrt(u_xlat6.x);
            u_xlat9 = u_xlat4.x * 0.5;
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb6 = !!(u_xlat6.x<u_xlat9);
    #else
            u_xlatb6 = u_xlat6.x<u_xlat9;
    #endif
            u_xlatb6 = u_xlatb6 && u_xlatb1;
            if(u_xlatb6){
                    SV_Target0 = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5);
                    return;
            //ENDIF
            }
            } else {
            u_xlati6 = u_xlati_loop_2 + 1;
            u_xlat1.xy = Value[u_xlati6].xy + Value[u_xlati_loop_2].xy;
            u_xlat9 = (-Value[u_xlati_loop_2].y) + Value[u_xlati6].y;
            u_xlat7.xy = (-Value[u_xlati6].xy) + Value[u_xlati_loop_2].xy;
            u_xlat2 = u_xlat7.x * gl_FragCoord.y;
            u_xlat2 = u_xlat9 * gl_FragCoord.x + u_xlat2;
            u_xlat2 = Value[u_xlati6].x * Value[u_xlati_loop_2].y + u_xlat2;
            u_xlat6.x = (-Value[u_xlati6].y) * Value[u_xlati_loop_2].x + u_xlat2;
            u_xlat7.xy = u_xlat7.xy * u_xlat7.xy;
            u_xlat9 = u_xlat9 * u_xlat9 + u_xlat7.x;
            u_xlat9 = sqrt(u_xlat9);
            u_xlat6.x = abs(u_xlat6.x) / u_xlat9;
            u_xlat9 = u_xlat7.y + u_xlat7.x;
            u_xlat9 = sqrt(u_xlat9);
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb6 = !!(1.0>=u_xlat6.x);
    #else
            u_xlatb6 = 1.0>=u_xlat6.x;
    #endif
            u_xlat1.xy = (-u_xlat1.xy) * vec2(0.5, 0.5) + gl_FragCoord.xy;
            u_xlat1.xy = u_xlat1.xy * u_xlat1.xy;
            u_xlat1.x = u_xlat1.y + u_xlat1.x;
            u_xlat1.x = sqrt(u_xlat1.x);
            u_xlat9 = u_xlat9 * 0.5;
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb9 = !!(u_xlat1.x<u_xlat9);
    #else
            u_xlatb9 = u_xlat1.x<u_xlat9;
    #endif
            u_xlatb6 = u_xlatb9 && u_xlatb6;
            if(u_xlatb6){
                    SV_Target0 = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5);
                    return;
            //ENDIF
            }
            //ENDIF
            }
    }
    for(int u_xlati_loop_3 = 0 ; u_xlati_loop_3<PointNum ; u_xlati_loop_3++)
    {
            TempArray0[u_xlati_loop_3].x = Value[u_xlati_loop_3].x;
            TempArray1[u_xlati_loop_3].x = Value[u_xlati_loop_3].y;
    }
    u_xlati1.y = 0;
    u_xlati1.x = u_xlati0;
    u_xlati3 = 0;
    while(true){
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb6 = !!(u_xlati1.y>=PointNum);
    #else
            u_xlatb6 = u_xlati1.y>=PointNum;
    #endif
            if(u_xlatb6){break;}
            u_xlat6.x = TempArray1[u_xlati1.y].x;
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            { bool cond = gl_FragCoord.y<u_xlat6.x; u_xlati9 = int(!!cond ? 0xFFFFFFFFu : uint(0u)); }
    #else
            u_xlati9 = int((gl_FragCoord.y<u_xlat6.x) ? 0xFFFFFFFFu : uint(0u));
    #endif
            u_xlat7.x = TempArray1[u_xlati1.x].x;
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            { bool cond = gl_FragCoord.y<u_xlat7.x; u_xlati10 = int(!!cond ? 0xFFFFFFFFu : uint(0u)); }
    #else
            u_xlati10 = int((gl_FragCoord.y<u_xlat7.x) ? 0xFFFFFFFFu : uint(0u));
    #endif
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb9 = !!(u_xlati9!=u_xlati10);
    #else
            u_xlatb9 = u_xlati9!=u_xlati10;
    #endif
            u_xlat10 = TempArray0[u_xlati1.x].x;
            u_xlat2 = TempArray0[u_xlati1.y].x;
            u_xlat10 = u_xlat10 + (-u_xlat2);
            u_xlat5 = (-u_xlat6.x) + gl_FragCoord.y;
            u_xlat10 = u_xlat10 * u_xlat5;
            u_xlat6.x = (-u_xlat6.x) + u_xlat7.x;
            u_xlat6.x = u_xlat10 / u_xlat6.x;
            u_xlat6.x = u_xlat2 + u_xlat6.x;
    #ifdef UNITY_ADRENO_ES3
            u_xlatb6 = !!(gl_FragCoord.x<u_xlat6.x);
    #else
            u_xlatb6 = gl_FragCoord.x<u_xlat6.x;
    #endif
            u_xlatb6 = u_xlatb6 && u_xlatb9;
            u_xlati9 = ~u_xlati3;
            u_xlati3 = (u_xlatb6) ? u_xlati9 : u_xlati3;
            u_xlati1.x = u_xlati1.y + 1;
            u_xlati1.xy = u_xlati1.yx;
    }
    if(u_xlati3 != 0) {
            SV_Target0 = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.300000012);
            return;
    //ENDIF
    }
    SV_Target0 = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    return;
    }

    #endif


    -- Fragment shader for "gles3":
    Shader Disassembly:
    // All GLSL source is contained within the vertex program

    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float4` instead of `vector`:

```
// Upgrade NOTE: excluded shader from DX11 because it uses wrong array syntax (type[size] name)
// #pragma exclude_renderers d3d11
...
uniform float4 Value[6];
```

This gets compiled as `uniform highp vec4 Value[6];` for gles.